# stuck {in/at} beta

Tags: prepositions, computing

You can be "stuck **at** home", "stuck **at** the airport" or "...**at** a certain level" e.g. *Today, inflation is still low, but unemployment is stuck at a painfully high level.* But you are "stuck **in** the middle", "stuck **in** the suburbs" and "stuck **in** debt".

So, what about a virtual entity or state such as "beta"?

> ***beta***
>   **4.** also: a stage of development in which a product is nearly complete but not yet ready for release ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beta))

Is a product or site stuck IN or AT beta?

1. It shouldn't be stuck ***in*** beta
2. It shouldn't be stuck ***at*** beta

Is there a reason why one preposition should be preferred over the other?

Comment: In the context of your project, is 'beta' a place (e.g. a milestone) or a (sub-)process? You're stuck _at_ a place but stuck _in_ a process.

Comment: You'll be using a metaphor either way, as you're not talking about a physical location or a specific time / timespan. // Though there are many more Google hits for 'stuck in B/beta', most seem to refer to problems encountered when using a beta version rather than the problem that progress beyond the beta version seems far off. If the latter is what is meant, the 'attain a level' metaphor rather than the container metaphor is what is required for enhanced clarity: **at**. However, _in_ is not 'wrong' here, just not the better choice (unless a nuance of 'wallowing in the problem' is wanted).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth it would be nice if you converted your comment into an answer, and then I would wait and see whether the upvotes confirmed your claim that "at" is the better choice.

Comment: I'm not, of course, going to be able to add authoritative support for the view. And other answers have now echoed and enlarged upon the comment. You yourself use 'stuck at a certain level'; the level is labelled 'Beta' in this case. FF writes 'the (semantically trivial) difference between _at_ and _in_ is just a matter of whether you visualise the circumstances as being unable to advance past a certain point in the development process, or trapped in a constraining situation'. Either is possible; I'd certainly say the former visualisation is, as per Occam's razor, the sensible one.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth why wouldn't you be able to do that? You seem to be adding even more arguments in your second comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both prepositions are fine. Consider a less metaphorical context where you're constrained to remain somewhere that really ***is*** a physical location...

> 1: *I was [stuck **at** the office](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22stuck%20at%20the%20office%22) all day yesterday.*
>    2: *I was [stuck **in** the office](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22stuck%20in%20the%20office%22) all day yesterday.*

...where both versions have links to at least hundreds of relevant instances in Google Books. And in terms of *relative* prevalence, there's [this NGram usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stuck%20in%20the%20office%2Cstuck%20at%20the%20office&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstuck%20in%20the%20office%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstuck%20at%20the%20office%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cstuck%20in%20the%20office%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstuck%20at%20the%20office%3B%2Cc0)...

[image]

In principle a speaker *might* make a considered choice between the metaphorical ***container*** reference *(**in**)* or the ***position*** reference *(**at**)*. The "container" mode is more appropriate if the weather was pleasant, but you couldn't go ***out*** (you had to remain ***inside***), whereas the "location" reference *(**at**)* is better if you couldn't go somewhere further ***away*** (down the road to watch tennis at Wimbledon, say, if your office is in London).

In practice that distinction isn't always relevant, and it isn't always accurately reflected by the choice of preposition anyway (native speakers aren't necessarily *that* precise on such matters.

---

With an even more metaphorical context such as...

> 3: *Our new killer app has been stuck **at** beta for months.*
>    4: *Our new killer app has been stuck **in** beta for months.*
>    5: *Our new killer app has been stuck **on** beta for months.*

...the (semantically trivial) difference between ***at*** and ***in*** is just a matter of whether you visualise the circumstances as being ***unable to advance past a certain point*** in the development process, or ***trapped in a constraining situation***.

But per #5 above, we can also use a ***surface*** metaphor *(**on**)* - which is perhaps better understood in this particular case as a "level" (of advancement ***up*** through vertically-oriented stages, as in...

> 6: *I'm stuck **on** level 3 with my new SuperMario video game*.

---

TLDR: It doesn't really matter which preposition you use, but if you understand the nature of the underlying metaphoric relationship, you might want to take account of this when making your choice (so your words truly reflect *what you want to say*, not *what you think someone else might say*).

Answer (score 5):

Both work, but the nuance is different.

With *stuck in beta*, what is conveyed is that the process is still underway - the development is metaphorically stuck inside the process. With *stuck at beta*, it is the state that is conveyed, not a process - the release hasn't progressed beyond the beta phase.

Here are a few examples using "stuck at beta *x*" to indicate that no version beyond *beta x* is available. Note that it is not the case that the *beta x* version has not yet been released.

- So, wait, do we have to pay again if we bought it in beta or not? And where do you get the newest version? My game is stuck at beta 1.8 and won't update.
  [- KarmaTheAlligator, The Escapist Portal](https://v1.escapistmagazine.com/forums/read/7.323401-Minecraft-Is-Finished?page=3)
- Can we get a link for [IOS] 8.2 beta 1 or 2 because [s]ome of us are stuck at beta 5[?]
  [- Kody Terrell Whitehead, idownloadblog forum][2](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2015/02/23/taig-windows-jailbreak-ios-8-2-beta/)

Here are a couple of examples using "stuck in beta" to indicate a longer-than-expected process. Note that these examples show a process they can't get out of:

- I opted into the Beta a few months ago. After the device began to crash a lot I tried to get out. I un-enrolled from the Beta but never received an update back to stable. I factory reset the phone, but when I swipe down it still shows as in the Android Beta program in the settings page.
  [- Leigh Llweelyn, Pixel Phone Help forum](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/forum/AAAAb4-OgUsqYBN6JgIDQw/?hl=en&gpf=d/topic/phone-by-google/qYBN6JgIDQw)
- All said, it appears the Spanish e-book industry is still stuck in Beta. The pivotal and innovative collaborative e-book distribution program announced earlier this year by Spain’s Big Three—Random House Mondadori, Planeta and Santillana—is now scheduled to ramp up for spring 2010.  Meanwhile, Spain’s Ministry of Culture is expected to issue a government report concerning e-book policy in mid-January.
  [- Emily Williams, Publishing Perspectives](https://publishingperspectives.com/2009/11/spains-e-book-business-stuck-in-beta/)

All told, the two phrases are fairly similar. Something *stuck in beta* is delayed by the process. Something *stuck at beta* simply hasn't been (or can't be) upgraded further, without any reference to a holdup in the process.

Answer (score 2):

Ciao,

as a non native speaker who moved to Australia since 4 years I appreciated your question and I think the answer is simpler than what you think

Forget the "stuck at/in" existence just for a second

In your daily talks you say: "I'm at home", "I'm at the airport", "I'm at your level". You also say "I'm in the middle", "I'm in the suburbs", "I'm in debt". Do you get where I'm pointing, right?

In IT we say that "your product is in beta". So "your product is stuck in beta"

Hope it helps

Thanks and have a good weekend,
Antonino

Comment: Yet, it is also possible to say that you are *in* an airport and to be *on* the same level as someone. Prepositions are never easy...

Answer (score 0):

You may say that your software is stuck *in* beta testing, and that the version number is stuck *at* beta.